# Kali apt-get update not working as it should

Tags: apt, kali-linux

Whenever I do `apt-get update` on my Kali system, it only downloads from one source.

```
root@anonymous # apt-get update
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

What should I do?

---

My `sources.list` is fine:

```
root@anonymous:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` is working as intended.

Only the `sources.lst` lines beginning with the `deb` keyword are used in downloading regular binary packages.

The lines beginning with the `deb-src` keyword are for downloading source packages only, e.g. with `apt-get source <package name>`. You would use that only if you plan to compile a package from source code, for example because you have an experimental source code patch for it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your sources list in `/etc/apt/sources.list.`, It got modified somehow probably and/or your sources list might be probably missing or commented out the sources.

Here is the list of their resources [Kali Linux Sources List](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

try to edit your `sources.list`, I believe it is in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

---

Only one source are included in `sources.list` in kali linux so it's basically normal.

> Kali rolling users should have these entries in their
> `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:
>
> `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

The deb-src is optional.

> In case you require source packages, you might also want to add the following repositories as well:
> `deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

*Source: https://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq*

Comment: deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib<br>
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

Comment: my sources.lst is fine i wanna know why it does that

Comment: Try restarting your device, or probably do this `apt-get clean`.

Comment: did that but still :(

Comment: Did you do anything before this happened?, have you tried to rollback to a snapshot before this happened?

Comment: i had more error before this happened, had to edit /etc/apt//apt.conf.d/local

Comment: Then your error **probably** exists there, try reading the file for possible errors. If you ask me, I would just go back to a backup/snapshot before this things happened.

Comment: but kali is installed as main OS on my pc

Comment: Does installing a package works? try doing `apt-get upgrade`, if it all works, what is the problem? I mean the docs shows that there really is one sources only listed on the `sources.list` refer to this "https://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq".

Comment: yes 'apt-get upgrade' works and installing packages also works

Comment: Then your device is actually fine.